# Using Mean.io - How to disable JS files aggregation

Tags: mean.io

During development I'd like to have original (not aggregated) `.js` files loaded.

Mean.io documentation says:

> All javascript within public is automatically aggregated with the exception of files in assets.

This is my file structure:

```
public            
  --- assets        # Javascript/Css/Images (not aggregated)
  --- controllers
  --- config
  --- services
  --- views
```

How to disable aggregation for all `.js` files in public?

Comment: I am also interested in an answer to this.  The aggregated assets is great for a prod deployment but a real pain for local development, debugging, and testing!   To clarify, I would prefer a 'dev' mode where the launched nodejs server would serve up the local javascript files as-is.

Comment: +1 on this. I'm about to abandon mean.io for something else due to the difficulty in Chrome debugging mean.io. The "make pretty" in the tools button doesn't always work for sorting things out.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the version 0.6.16. You can set the

> aggregate:false

in the config/env/.js file to disable aggregation of js and css files